# Trouble with shared classes when converting to ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have two targets in my project with overlapping classes.

I converted one target to arc and now I can't convert second target, beacues files common with first target are already converted. Unchecking these files during conversion not working.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. The most painless method I figured out was to add second target as build dependency to the first one. Select both in conversion dialogue, and then remove this dependency after conversion. It 100% works.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems in the past.   The solutions that I came up with weren't particularly elegant, but they did work.

If the second target has a small amount of changes over the first, you can go in to Xcode and change the `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` setting to `YES` for the second project and then manually fix the problems.   This works OK for a small number of files, but isn't as comprehensive.

For significant changes, I ended up using my source control system (Perforce in my case, but git, hg, whatever should work fine) to temporarily roll back my changes for the first target and re-apply them to the second target so that I could use the automated tools, then I did a diff between the files that were changed in both runs to make sure that the changes were the same (I don't recall any differences).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the diffirence is about 70 unconverted classes makes 1st approach impossible ). I'm about to try add second target as a build dependency to the first one end convert both at once.